# PHP 5 imagesetpixel parameters

Tags: php, gd

I have a quick question regarding PHP's function imagesetpixel. According to the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php), the final parameter is a color identifier created with imagecolorallocate. This makes sense. However I found a typo in my program where I was passing hex values directly to imagesetpixel, and it was still working just fine. Is this expected behavior? It's not mentioned in the documentation, so I'm inclined to just stick to using color identifiers, but I figured I'd ask just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what `imagecolorallocate()` does: https://bitbucket.org/libgd/gd-libgd/src/de7acbfe3e9e43b6b74b740e192915aff4e45a5d/src/gd.c?at=master#cl-518

Basically, it spits out an RGBA value compressed to an `int`. You can do this because and `int` has 4 bytes and you need one byte to represent each color.

Now when you pass any value into `imagesetpixel()` that PHP can convert to an integer, it will work.

You could even do this yourself (not tested, may not work with truecolor contexts):

```
$im_color = pack('SSSS', $r, $g, $b, $a);
```

Of course this entire behaviour is subject to change in any future version of GD, which is probably why it's not documented.

Comment: Now when you pass any value into `imagesetpixel()` that PHP can convert to an integer, it will work, unless the developers decide to change the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will stick to using it as intended of course, but thanks for pointing out how it's working under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not documented, you do not have the right to expect anything. Any correlation beween your expectation and actual bahviour is either documented, or must be regarded as happening by chance.

Comment: I figured as much, but I'm no expert in PHP - it's been years since I've used it. Just making sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: This is not a specialty of PHP. It's a fundamental principle where two sotware components interact.

Comment: I understand that, but when I last used PHP years ago it was a pile of shite. I did something by accident and it worked - who knows if it's desired behavior or not when it's PHP? :-p